# What was so terrible about "the void" in haven?

Tags: haven

In the lighthouse episode both William and Dave describe the void as a terrible place and to be stranded there as the most terrible fate. Dave even panicked and was willing to kill his brother to prevent going there.
Later we see that the void is a rocky landscape with dead trees and that William seems to be able to live there without much problems. He was not ragged, starved or gone mad or insane (at least not more than he was before) when he met Nathan. He even "greets" him whith a laughing.
Of cource it is not a pleasant place. But it does not seem more terrible than to be in jail.
So the descriptions of the void seems very exaggerated. And I expected more esoteric "pains" there and not just a rough landscape. More something like hell with tortures and so on.

So what was so especially terrible about the void?